# How do I make the PySimpleGui table show multiple items per line?

Tags: pysimplegui

If I try to display lines of text in a table, it cuts the text off at the first word for each line.

If I use the text

```
salv.e               ADJ    1 1 VOC S M POS               Always    mostfreq
 [XXXAX]      veryfreq
well, unharmed, sound; alive; safe, saved;
salv.e               V      2 1 PRES ACTIVE  IMP 2 S      Always    mostfreq
 [XXXBX]      frequent
be well/in good health; [salve => hello/hail/greetings; farewell/goodbye];
salve                ADV    POS                           Always    mostfreq
 [XXXDX]      lesser
hail!/welcome!; farewell!; [salvere jubere => to greet/bid good day];
```

It displays as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQz2b.png).

My table is set up like this:

`[Table(values=[[1], [4]], headings = ['Output'], num_rows=20, key="table", expand_x=True, justification='left', expand_y=True)]`

and the data is given to the table as:

```
data = "salv.e               ADJ    1 1 VOC S M POS               Always    mostfreq
 [XXXAX]      veryfreq
well, unharmed, sound; alive; safe, saved;
salv.e               V      2 1 PRES ACTIVE  IMP 2 S      Always    mostfreq
 [XXXBX]      frequent
be well/in good health; [salve => hello/hail/greetings; farewell/goodbye];
salve                ADV    POS                           Always    mostfreq
 [XXXDX]      lesser
hail!/welcome!; farewell!; [salvere jubere => to greet/bid good day];".split('\n')

window['table'].update((data))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data for a Table should be in the format, List in List.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

data = """
salv.e               ADJ    1 1 VOC S M POS               Always    mostfreq
 [XXXAX]      veryfreq
well, unharmed, sound; alive; safe, saved;
salv.e               V      2 1 PRES ACTIVE  IMP 2 S      Always    mostfreq
 [XXXBX]      frequent
be well/in good health; [salve => hello/hail/greetings; farewell/goodbye];
salve                ADV    POS                           Always    mostfreq
 [XXXDX]      lesser
hail!/welcome!; farewell!; [salvere jubere => to greet/bid good day];""".strip().split('\n')

width = max(map(len, data)) + 1             # Get the max width of each line
data = [[item] for item in data]            # Set the format of data to list of list

sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 16))    # Mono-space font for exact width to display
layout = [
    [
        sg.Table(
            values=data,
            headings=['Output'],
            auto_size_columns=False,
            col_widths=[width],
            num_rows=20,
            key="table",
            expand_x=True,
            justification='left',
            expand_y=True,
        ),
    ],
]
sg.Window("Title", layout).read(close=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Oh thank you for your answer. I guess I should pay more attention to my formatting. Also, if I try to run your code by itself, it gives the error:

```sg.theme('DarkGreen')
    ^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'PySimpleGUI' has no attribute 'theme' (most likely due to a circular import)```

Comment: Maybe you use `PySimpleGUI.py` as your py filename ?

Comment: I installed it with pip, and its version `4.60.5 Released 21-May-2023`

Comment: I mean maybe you used the `PySimpleGUI` as your script filename, so it didn't import the library, but your script file.

Comment: Oh no its named 'test.py' so thats not it. I think it only happens to me if I do 'import PySimpleGUI as sg'

Comment: Check what imported if you got a message like "most likely due to a circular import".